# How to determine two functions are cloned without comparing their outputs and signatures?

Tags: java, function, methods, analysis

```
int factorial ( int n )
{
   if ( n == 0)
      return 1;
  else
      return n * factorial (n -1);
}
```

The above function and the following function perform the same functionality.  Syntactically dissimilar code fragments that implement the same functionality called Type-4 code clone. They are also known as semantic or functional clone

```
 int factorial ( int n )
{
   int i , fact =1;
   for ( i =1; i <= n; i ++)
       fact = fact * i ;
   return fact;
}
```

Now, my question is how can I determine these two functions are cloned without comparing their outputs and signatures?

Comment: Well, they're not really clones of each other, as they both implement the same functionality in completely different ways.

Comment: There is absolutely no way of doing this

Comment: They are not clone to each other, They simply provide same output, with different implementations.

Comment: Whole PhD thesises or complex products like TeamScale were built around such questions. Don't assume that a simple SO question could ever cover this. Way too broad.

Comment: The only thing to hope for : an explanation why this can not be done :-)

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't do that.

Assume the first method stops on a specific input.

In order to find "clones" that follow your definition, one would have to find if any other part of the program that stops on whatever input.

In other words, you would have to solve the halting problem. 
And as you hopefully know, that one can not be solved.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the Halting Problem can only tell us that there is no program that will give the correct answer for all possible inputs (i.e. all pairs of functions).  In theory, it is possible to write one that works for some inputs.

Comment: I am not fully sure either. But I think : in the end he asks to find any two methods that "do the same thing"; not specifically looking at any special input values. And from that perspective, I find my answer to make a profound argument that this requirement can not be resolved.